Label not updating on BackGroundWorker work
I tried to search for solutions, but none work, so I'm asking directly. I'm using a BackGroundWorker and while I'm drawing a Bitmap I'd like to show it in the PictureBox. It seems tricky to do, so at least I wanted to show a progress percentage in a label, but the label does not update during the process.
The Work calls a function passing parameters (a Bitmap and a String). To show the value in the label, I'd use the ProgressChange event (also it's what you'd expect since it's literally stated in a MS Docs example). During the function, I`m doing this:
uint dimen = (uint)pbo.Width * (uint)pbo.Height;
uint count = 0;
Bitmap pbn = new Bitmap(pbo, new Size(pbo.Width * 2, pbo.Height * 2));
for loop (some values)
{
  //do stuff
  count++;
  backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((count / dimen) * 100), text);
}
for loop (other values)
{
  //do stuff
  count++;
  backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((count / dimen) * 100), text);
}
for loop (other values)
{
  //do stuff
  count++;
  backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((count / dimen) * 100), text);
}

Literally, the progress event just calls label1.Text =  $"{e.UserState} {e.ProgressPercentage}%";. Whatever you don't see in this code doesn't matter. This is mainly the part that doesn't work.
The report function of the BGW is set to true (in fact it kinda works but not as I'd expect since it seems to work very slowly, meaning not during my function, or not at all).
I know I'm not refreshing. And I don't see why I should, since MS Docs don't do that. If I try to refresh the label after setting its content like that, I get this error:
Full error message:

Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' : 'Transition into COM context 0xad4f80 for this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed with the following error: An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010D (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL)). This is typically because the COM context 0xad4f80 where this RuntimeCallableWrapper was created has been disconnected or it is busy doing something else and cannot process the context transition. No proxy will be used to service the request on the COM component and calls will be made to the COM component directly. This may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all COM contexts/apartments/threads stay alive and are available for context transition, until the application is completely done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represents COM components that live inside them.

Any ideas on how to change the code and still maintain this kind of structure? I also mean continuing using the BGW.

A common and recurring issue with BackGroundWorker's progress reporting is freezing the UI by reporting progress too frequently. Please reduce the frequency that you report progress, and see if this solves the problem. If not, please update the question accordingly.

Btw the BackgroundWorker is an aged technology (it has aged like milk, not wine). You could look here for a more modern alternative.

I did it limiting the reporting to if (count % 100 == 0) and I also tried changing the label text as label1.Invoke(new Action(() => { label1.Text = $"{e.UserState} {e.ProgressPercentage}%"; })); A part of my issue was also that I misjudged calculations based on common sense. Having the variables as uint made (a / b) be equal to 0 until the process ending, so the value passed to the reporter was constantly 0 * 100 until it reached 1 * 100 ( so basically I read 0% until it reached 100%). Instead of that I passed count * 100 / dimen and it works.
I also tried a solution to show instead the PictureBox filling each pixel but I found out it's a really slow process, because there are 2 ways I think but they both require a refresh I suppose: one is to set every now and then (after each 1000 pixel perhaps?) the PictureBox.Image = //temporary filled Bitmap but this makes the image blink each time it's refreshed and the other one instead is in fact not to set the full image but only draw the single pixel which instead cannot be done every 1000 pixels (because it wouldn't be an actual real-time display of the result) and it actually needs to be done for each pixel; not sure if this can avoid the blinking but surely would be way more time-needing/wasting. So for now I gave up on the idea of showing the image filling, it's a nice idea but I'd prefer performance over fancy idea.
